Can you use CONCAT and Substitute together in Excel?
I am looking join firstname and surname together. This I have working fine using the following:
=CONCAT([@[First Name]]," ",[@Surname])

However some of the surnames have values in brackets. For example Smith (Dance)
How can I combine firstname and surname, while removing the brackets after the surname?
Thank you in advance.
I've tried the following:
=Substitute(("d2,"(chat)",""),CONCAT([@[first name]]," ",[@surname]))

D2 is the cell that contains the surname Smith (Dance)

You have to double substitute the brackets: =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,"(",""),")","") which will result in Smith Dance.

If you only want the text before the brackets, then it is easier to use TEXTBEFORE
=LET(
    cleanSurname,TEXTBEFORE([@Surname]," (",,,0,[@Surname]),
    [@[First Name]] & " " & cleanSurname
    )

Or as a one liner:
= [@[First Name]] & " " & TEXTBEFORE([@Surname]," (",,,0,[@Surname])

Thank you!  I was able to tweak your one liner so that it fit my sheet!

Perfect - if this solved your question, please mark it as an answer. What should I do when someone answers my question?

Replacing the first occurrence:
Without using LET:
=CONCAT([@[First Name]], " ", 
IFERROR(REPLACE([@Surname],  
FIND("(", [@Surname]), 
FIND(")", [@Surname]) -  
FIND("(", [@Surname]) + 1, ""), [@Surname]))

Preferred way:
=LET(
    lb, FIND("(", [@Surname]),
    num_chars, FIND(")", [@Surname]) - lb + 1,
    CONCAT(
        [@[First Name]],
        " ",
        IFERROR(REPLACE([@Surname], lb, num_chars, ""), [@Surname])
    )
)



Thank you for your response, My sheet is only accessed online by my coworkers. As a result, vb won't run.  I believe our IT department has some features locked out as well but your solution would have worked perfectly!

@user2008679, thanks for getting back. I'm not using VBA here. This is just using formula with functions available in Excel 2021 and later. @[First Name] etc. are used when using tables. Using structured references with Excel tables - Microsoft Support

@user2008679, I added an alternative without using LET, if you want to try.
